# I get TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] when I parsing my school website

Tags: python, parsing

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import urllib.request
import re
import os

os.system("cls")

url=input("Url Link : ")

if(url[0:8]=="https://"):
   url=url[:4]+url[5:]

if(url[0:7]!="http://"):
    url="http://"+url

value=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF8')
par='<title>(.+?)</title>'

result=re.findall(par,value) 
print(result)
```

It is title parsing program. It works well when parsing like Google, Gmail site. When try to parsing my school website the error comes out. It is the problem in school? Or in my code?

Comment: What's your school website? Is it accessible?

Comment: @aIKid Yes, It can access in Internet Explorer

Comment: what is the url you are giving?

Comment: @AnandSKumar It's Korean Website [link](http://jakjeon.icems.kr)

Comment: increase the timeout time

Comment: @VigneshKalai How to increase the timeout time?

Comment: See to this link on the official [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) page

Comment: that is  `value=urllib.request.urlopen(url,timeout=60).read().decode('UTF8')`

Comment: @VigneshKalai post it as an answer bro

Comment: @VigneshKalai Thanks for your comment

Comment: I tried it with Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and it returned in 1-2 sec with 200 status code and UTF-8 encoding but then got this encoding error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 600-601: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @TrisNefzger thanks for your try. It show error all school, using icems service

Comment: I can browse it with firefox no problem.  Whish I knew how to fix the encoding for python to download it.

Comment: @TrisNefzger You know how to solve this problem? I can browse it with IE,too

Comment: In Windows 7 cmd.exe console I ran chcp 65001  to change the code page to 65001 from 437.  Then I could download the entire  webpage instantly without error. However as it does not have Korean fonts a lot of the text is garbled like <h2 class="blind">í•˜ë‹¨ë§í¬</h2  and even this changed when pasting it in this message.  What Windows code page supports Korean and English fonts?

Comment: The Korean code page for Windows is 949.  I actually have it installed (in C:\Windows\SysWOW64) but cannot activate it just in the console -- my entire platform would have to be changed to Korean which is only possible for the Windows Ultimate or Enterprise versions.  I thought an option would be to run Korean page through Google translate to render it in English and download that, but it just produced a lot of Google JavaScript.

Comment: @TrisNefzger Im window8.1. I will go home 30minute later and read your comment .Sorry T.T .Because Im in academy

Comment: @TrisNefzger I do it in 65001, 437, 949. but it didn't work in my workspace can you give me screenshot when your program work. z9014z@naver.com plz T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) I was able to download http://jakjeon.icems.kr/main.do without error although some of the text was garbled due to inability to install the Korean code page (949) for Windows.

Here is the script:

```
import requests

url='http://jakjeon.icems.kr/main.do'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
print(r.text)
```

Running it printed:

```
200  # r.status_code
text/html; charset=UTF-8 # r.headers['content-type']
UTF-8 # r.encoding
```

Followed by all of the text of the page (r.text)

This printed successfully to the Windows cmd.exe console only after setting its code page to 65001 (Unicode (UTF-8), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Attempting to redirect output to a file resulted in a UnicodeEncodeError because the default Windows encoding for a file on my platform is code page 1252 (ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows)). Here is the error message from attempting to print to a file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "URLDownloadDemo.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(r.text)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 600-601: character maps to <undefined>
```

Then entire cmd.exe console transcript is available at https://goo.gl/Cyav17 and a copy of the script is at https://goo.gl/W4Sk9S.

Due to the encoding error when redirecting output to a file, I enhanced the script to write its output directly to a file with UTF-8 encoding.  Here is the new script:

```
import requests

url='http://jakjeon.icems.kr/main.do'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
fout = open('URLDownloadDemo.output.txt', mode='wt', encoding='UTF-8')
fout.write(r.text)
fout.close()
```

Running this worked perfectly (no errors) and the output file contained Korean alphabet symbols identical to those in the source of the web page.

The new script is available at https://goo.gl/VJs2Na and its output file is at https://goo.gl/4BKe8C.

Comment: I met Error in 1st line "import requests"

Comment: Try running 'pip install requests' first.  See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/.

Comment: Sorry T-T I don't know how can i install the program T-T

Comment: The installation instructions are at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/.  If you have difficulty reading that due to language, put that URL into Google Translate at https://translate.google.com/ and translate it into whatever language is best for you.  If you do not have pip or easy_install  I recommend getting the most recent Anaconda release of Python which includes pip.  Anaconda Python is available for download at http://continuum.io/downloads.

Comment: I updated the script to write encoded output directly to a file and this worked perfectly.  The new script is available at https://goo.gl/VJs2Na and its output file is at https://goo.gl/4BKe8C.  My answer has been updated with this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the timeout

code:

```
value=urllib.request.urlopen(url,timeout=60).read().decode('UTF8')
```

Comment: another Error appear "ConnectionResetError [WinError 10054]". I should give up?

Comment: Could you say about the full error was it just connectionreset error or connection reset by peer error and `never say the word give up` :D

Comment: ConnectionResetError [WinError 10054] In this connection it was forcibly closed by the remote host. It is Error message. It show error all school, using icems service.